# On the definition of a merely ample line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb P^N$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $n$ with a fixed ample line bundle $L$. We know what is meant by a very ample line bundle.

At this point, my question is: What is meant by "Consider the above $L$ to be merely ample"? In other words, what is the definition of a *merely ample* line bundle?

I couldn't find any reference for this definition. Can someone give me a reference?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a technical definition, the author just means a line bundle which is ample but not very ample. See for instance the dictionary definition of "merely" available from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/merely).

Comment: Do you mean $L$ is ample and is not very ample with respect to $\mathbb P^N$?

Comment: No. The typical setup here is that we're working with schemes over a base $S$, and we consider line bundles on $X$ which are ample or very ample with respect to the structure morphism.

Comment: for a projective variety can we not consider $S =\mathbb P^N$?

Comment: When you say a projective variety, projective over what?

Comment: over $\mathbb C$

Comment: Then the base is $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C$ and we mean ample or very ample with respect to the structure morphism $X\to \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb C$.

Comment: can we say that $L$ is never isomorphic to $i^*(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^N}(l))$, for any positive integer $l$?, where $i :X \to \mathbb P^N$ is the closed immersion.

Comment: This is too many extra questions for you to ask in the comments. I have answered the question in your post and you have accepted the answer. If you have further issues, please ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, I will separately ask these questions.